# fscanf returns wrong numbers

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to read a text file that looks like this

```
8
6 1 2.2
1 2 1.0
4 3
1 3
4 5 1.2
2 4 0.0
5 2
6 6
3 4
```

This is my code

```
int nodes;
FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
fscanf(file, "%d",  &nodes);
printf("n = %d\n", nodes);

while (1) {

    int node = 0, link = 0;
    float weight = 0.0;

    if (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f \n", &node, &link, &weight) < 1) {
        break;
    } else {
        printf("%d %d %.1f \n", node, link, weight);
    }
}
```

And this is the output

```
n = 8

6 1 2.2
1 2 1.0
4 3 1.0 
3 4 5.0 
1 0 0.0
```

Comment: `fscanf()` doesn't care about newlines; white space is white space. It reads three numbers, including newlines. The trailing blanks and newline in the format string are mostly noise — to the extent they're not noise, they're a user-interface disaster if a user is ever typing the input.  If you need line-based input, use [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) or
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) to read lines and
[`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html).

Comment: `fscanf()` returns "the number of input items successfully matched and assigned" -- you should be checking if it `== 3` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If you format your input differently you notice the error easy

```
8
6 1 2.2
1 2 1.0
4 3 1
3 4 5
1.2 2 4
0.0 5 2
6 6 3
4
```

When `fscanf` attempts to read `1.2` with conversion `"%d"` it assigns `1` to the corresponding variable and keeps the dot in the buffer for the next read.

The next read is again with conversion `"%d"` which does not accept a dot as valid input.